# JQuery 1 function many divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Suppose I have lots of divs: tens, hundreds, thousands that I'm creating using a php loop. I'd like one to slidetoggle by clicking its associated other. I can use php to give echo out each one with a unique class name like name1, name2, name3 etc.

How can I use 1 jQuery function to handle every div and associated div? The only solution I can seem to come up with is using PHP to output a function for each div and its associated div.

i.e.

```
<?php
echo '<script>';
    for(int x=0; x < numDivPairs; x++ ) {
        $( ".slideme".concat(x) ).hide(); //for every line of jquery, something like this
echo '</script>';
?>
```

This is, I'm sure, terrible practice if for no other reason than it will dramatically increase the page loading time. There must be a more elegant solution.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/farghole22/uvfh1znr/

Answer (score 1):

Since your class names are starting with `name`,You can use attribute starts with selector.

```
$("[class^='name']").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("nameDown").next().slideToggle();

});
```

FYI- You can use same class name for multiple elements

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uvfh1znr/2/)

Comment: This answer is by far the best, as no HTML code has to be changed.

Comment: Yup that's right. But it should use the method chaining rather using `$(this)` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use same `class` names and `next` to find the next `div` of the current element. This can help -

**HTML**

```
<div class="name">click me</div>
<div class="slideme">asdfojpasdfoiasdjasodijasdoifjasdf</div>
<hr>
<div class="name">click me</div>
<div class="slideme">asdfojpasdfoiasdjasodijasdoifjasdf</div>
<hr>
<div class="name">click me</div>
<div class="slideme">asdfojpasdfoiasdjasodijasdoifjasdf</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".name").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("nameDown").next(".slideme").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uvfh1znr/4/)